# Mysql username problems

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let's say i have following table layout:

```
Logs:
log_id - log_userfrom - log_userto

Users
user_id - user_name
```

**The result i need is like:**

```
Joe Adams - Andy Simons
```

How do i get that with a query?
I tried something like

```
SELECT `log_userfrom`, `log_userto`, `user_fullname` FROM pub_logcontact, pub_users
WHERE log_userfrom=user_id
```

The problem with above sql line is that its printing only username for userfrom.
I need it to print username for both userfrom and userto in one query :)

Is that possible? :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to join usernames to your logged values.

```
SELECT usersfrom.`username` AS `username_from`, usersto.`username` AS `username_to`
FROM `logs` logs
LEFT JOIN `users` usersfrom ON (usersfrom.`user_id`=logs.`log_userfrom`)
LEFT JOIN `users` usersto ON (usersto.`user_id`=logs.`log_userto`)
```

Comment: @DanBracuk In order to include `NULL` username values. An `INNER JOIN` would work, too, but won't return rows with `NULL` usernames. Am I understanding your question correctly?